# Live unwrap does not work with some objects

Tags: uv

I'm trying to use Live Unwrap with subdivided cube's UV, no matter what vertices I pin it just does not work (I made sure that 'Live Unwrap' checkbox is checked), what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Here is the .Blend file: [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with edge selection it works correctly that way Good luck

Answer (score 1):

In order for live unwrap to work on the above island it should be divided into two islands or more, live unwrap can not work on the whole island of the object at once.

You can choose part of the island and hide the rest (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> ) with the 'UV and edit mode selection sync' on